# MySQL query for latest record per user

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like:

```
id_primary, id_user, amount, date
```

If I have entries that look like:

```
1, 1, 5, 2012-01-05
2, 1, 8, 2012-01-15
3, 1, 17, 2012-03-30
4, 2, 3, 2012-01-18
5, 2, 9.5, 2012-01-31
```

I've tried multiple queries to get the latest result (chronologically) for each id_user, however I seem to get the first row available no matter what.  For example what I would want from this example table would be:

```
3, 1, 17, 2012-03-30
5, 2, 9.5, 2012-01-31
```

My latest attempt was something like this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM table a GROUP BY a.id_user HAVING MAX(a.date)
```

How can I fix this?  Do I need to use a nested query somehow?

Comment: @jcho360 he wants all the users - not just one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the `MAX()` date by user

```
select t1.id_primary,
  t1.id_user,
  t1.amount,
  t2.maxdate
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(date) maxdate, id_user
  from yourtable
  group by id_user
) t2
  on t1.id_user = t2.id_user
  and t1.date = t2.maxdate
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c405/2)

Comment: I tried something similar to this, but couldn't get it.  This worked great, thanks!

Comment: this make problem when same user id has same date. At that time we will get two rows for that user id.

Comment: @Pramod Yes that is correct if the user is has two entries with the same date then you would return 2 rows.

Answer (score 2):

I 100% agree with [@bluefeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202041/623041) (+1 btw), but in MySQL it can be abbreviated as follows:

```
SELECT yourtable.* FROM yourtable NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT id_user, MAX(date) date FROM yourtable GROUP BY id_user
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaa7b/1/0).

For your reference, this is known as the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

Answer (score 0):

This my statement for similar situation 
    $sql = "SELECT INDICADOR_IDIOMA FROM INDICADOR where INDICADOR_PK=(SELECT max(INDICADOR_PK) FROM INDICADOR WHERE INDICADOR_USUARIO=$pkUser)";